# Java VM7 and Java VM8 Math.sin benchmark comparison

Tags: java, math, benchmarking

I've implemented quick test in JMH

```
package org.sample;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import java.lang.Math;

public class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    public void testMethod() {
        // This is a demo/sample template for building your JMH benchmarks. Edit as needed.
        // Put your benchmark code here.
        Math.sin(1);
    }

}
```

Done benchmarking  on oracle-jvm-7 and oracle-jvm-8 (Gentoo Linux, Linux capitan 4.5.3-gentoo #2 SMP Wed May 11 09:57:24 EEST 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux)

Got these results:

```
============================================================================================                                                                                                  
oracle-jvm-7                                                                                                                                                                                  

Result "testMethod":                                                                                                                                                                          
  35528416.197 ±(99.9%) 645918.757 ops/s [Average]                                                                                                                                            
    (min, avg, max) = (14648664.448, 35528416.197, 37358723.432), stdev = 2734860.462                                                                                                         
      CI (99.9%): [34882497.440, 36174334.954] (assumes normal distribution)                                                                                                                  


# Run complete. Total time: 00:06:41                                                                                                                                                          

Benchmark                Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units                                                                                                                          
MyBenchmark.testMethod  thrpt  200  35528416.197 ± 645918.757  ops/s                                                                                                                          
============================================================================================                                                                                                  
oracle-jvm-8                                                                                                                                                                                  

Result "testMethod":                                                                                                                                                                          
  25471034.505 ±(99.9%) 883625.172 ops/s [Average]                                                                                                                                            
    (min, avg, max) = (10388072.812, 25471034.505, 27847466.635), stdev = 3741324.307                                                                                                         
      CI (99.9%): [24587409.334, 26354659.677] (assumes normal distribution)                                                                                                                  


# Run complete. Total time: 00:06:42                                                                                                                                                          

Benchmark                Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units                                                                                                                          
MyBenchmark.testMethod  thrpt  200  25471034.505 ± 883625.172  ops/s
```

Is there any specific reason that `Math.sin` gives 35528416.197 ops/s on JVM7 comparing to only 25471034.505 ops/s on JVM8?

Comment: Try testing empty method. It might be artifact of benchmarking framework behaving differently between JDK versions, rather than sin(..) itself.

Comment: @Artur Biesiadowski That makes benchmarking library totally useless.

Comment: have you checked it? Even if it is a case, it won't make it useless - because it should be used for checking your non-trivial code, rather than no-ops. If measurement overhead is let's say 50 versus 80 cpu cycles, it really won't matter if you are testing things which take seconds to complete. It might be even very cpu specific, with different jvms being faster or slower between versions on each cpu. I just wanted to point out it might something else than Math.sin itself.